# Singletons and ICommand

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, singleton, icommand

Is there some special rules I have to be careful about when binding my view to the commands defined in my singleton ViewModel, opposed to normal (non-singleton) ViewModels?

All my ViewModels except the one in question behave normally. Each of them exposes two public members called `HasChanges` (bool property) and `SaveChanges` (method) that I'm calling in the `CanExecute` and `Execute` functions of my commands.

While all other Views behave normally, enabling/disabling the buttons when the value of `HasChanges` changes and saving the contents when those buttons are clicked, the only ViewModel that implements Singleton pattern happens to call `CanExecute` only upon the first loading of the View.
After that, any number of `PropertyChanged` events raised from within that ViewModel (all my ViewModels implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`) do not affect the disabled state of the button.

Wondering what I'm missing here.

Here's the singleton ModelView:

```
Public NotInheritable Class MyViewModel
    Private Shared ReadOnly mInstance As New CommonListsViewModel

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As CommonListsViewModel
        Get
            Return mInstance
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property SaveChangesCommand As ICommand


    Private Sub New()
        SaveChangesCommand = New Commands.SaveChangesCommand()
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property HasChanges As Boolean Implements IEditorViewModel.HasChanges
        Get
            ...
        End Get
     End Property

    Public Function SaveChanges() As Boolean Implements IEditorViewModel.SaveChanges
        ...
    End Function
End Class
```

Here's the command:

```
Friend Class SaveChangesCommand
    Inherits CommandBase

    Public Overrides Function CanExecute(parameter As Object) As Boolean
        Return MyViewModel.Instance.HasChanges
    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub Execute(parameter As Object)
        MyViewModel.Instance.SaveChanges()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here's my View:

```
<Grid DataContext="{x:Static local:CommonListsViewModel.Instance}">
    <Button Command="{Binding SaveChangesCommand}">
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any difference in the behavior due to the fact that a class follows the singleton pattern. Anything with a reference to the singleton will not care how the construction of the class is restricted, only that the instance of the class exists.

The problem probably lies in a lack of a proper link between the PropertyChanged event of the ViewModel and the CanExecuteChanged on the Command.

Comment: :Correctly diagnosed. Thanks a bunch.